# Can you identify what web server is running on my localhost:8000?

Tags: windows-7, webserver

The web server doesn't start immediately; it starts after a few minutes of a fresh log in.
Resource Monitor shows that "System" is listening to port 8000.

I am using Windows 7 Professional.  I had [XAMMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) installed but they are removed.  I do have Visual Studio 2010 installed, but have not done any web development with it.

[image: Web server on localhost:8000]

Answer (score 3):

`netstat -ao` or [Sysinternals TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897437) list the sockets and the process that opened them. [Sysinternals ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653) shows the process and the services hosted by that process. This should help you track down which process/service is running the web server.

Comment: TCPView: Unable to query properties for System. While: System 4 TCP #hostname# 8000 #hostname# 0 LISTENING

Comment: @fen1kz Get the process ID from TCPView, then get the properties in ProcessExplorer.

Comment: hey, i've already provided process name and process PID - it is `system` process with PID = 4.